# showing error while im trying to override the run method

Tags: java

package com.jspiders.thread;

public class Mthrd1 extends Thread {
    {

```
    @Override
    //error line public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You should start [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) from the very basics

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid way to override the run method for creating threads:

```
class Test extends Thread
{
 public void run()
 {
      System.out.println("Thread Started and is Running");
  }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     Test t=new Test();
      t.start();
  }
}
```

There is also another way to create threads in java by implementing the runnable interface.  In you posted code you are calling the run method explicitly whereas, for calling the run method of Thread class you need to call start() method which implicitly calls the run method of Thread, your program is showing error because as you are calling run method explicitly and in your class you have no method called run.